# Log4j file not being created in spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, log4j, spring-data

This is my log4j.xml file. The file isn't being created and i don't know why, but I can see the log messages on the console.

Is there anything missing?
Is there something I should remove?

Thanks for taking a look and have a nice day.

```
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/paquitoelchocolatero.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" 
        value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<!-- Application logger -->
<logger name="springapp">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>
<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.transaction">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.orm">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.webflow">
    <level value="warn" />
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```

Comment: Try not using the `${catalina.home}` variable in your filepath (use absolute path instead). Does it work then?

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I solved the problem I needed the log for, so I don't need it anymore(for now).

Although it would be nice if someone could tell me what's wrong with thal configuration.